# log4j - attaching information (like MDC) using properties file

Tags: java, log4j

I'm currently using MDC in order to attached the environment of the current running application to the log. I do so because all the logs are sent to one LogStash server and I want to be able to differentiate between envs.

Since it's not a thread specific information but an application information I think I'm doing it wrong. Is there a way to just attached information to ALL logs using the properties files. something like:

```
log4j.appender.A.parameter=environment=production
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to append anything to ConversionPattern:

```
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=Production: %d [%t] %-5p [%c] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

or

```
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=${enviroment}: %d [%t] %-5p [%c] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

where `enviroment` is a system property.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't exactly the same. the log is getting to the other end as JSON with several fields such as "priority", "class" and "message" which is the message itself. Using MDC adds new fields to the json with their values. the layout will only alter the "message" field.